# Python Plotly chart - generate different y-axis for each facet_row

Tags: python-3.8, plotly-express

I am trying to plot a chart using plotly (v 5.11.0) where I am trying to generate different y-axis for each facet_row. The y-axis should be matching for all facet_cols within that facet_row.

using `fig.update_yaxes(matches = None)` doesn't seem to solve the above problem. Please suggest any solution if possible.

```
fig = px.bar(query_fb, x = "modelName",
                             y = "value", facet_col = "holdingPeriod",
                             facet_col_wrap = 3,
                             facet_row = 'dataItem',
                             color = "modelName")
fig.for_each_yaxis(lambda y: y.update(title = ''))
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(
                    text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))
yxs = dict(tickformat = yaxisfmt )
fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)
fig.update_yaxes(yxs, tickformat = yaxisfmt,hoverformat = yaxisfmt)
fig.update_layout(autosize=False,
                  width= 250*len(self.modelId),
                  height=600,
                  margin=dict(l=50, r=10, b=60, t=60),
                  #legend= dict(orientation="h",),
                  title_x = 0.2,title= "")
```

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, I figured the answer which worked for me. Thanks all!

```
for row_idx, row_figs in enumerate(fig._grid_ref): 
    for col_idx, col_fig in enumerate(row_figs):
          fig.update_yaxes(row=row_idx+1, col=col_idx+1,
                 matches = 'y'+str(len(row_figs)*row_idx+1))
```

Comment: What if I wanted to set my ymin, ymax to custom ranges that were not autodetected by the data's ymin / ymax, as your solution does? i.e., say the ymin, ymax of my first facet_row was -0.05 to 0.002 but I wanted to plot from -0.1 to 0.1? I tried using "range" instead of matches but it did not change each facet_row uniquely.